# is it possible to invoke an independent thread from Servlets?

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I have an independent JMS listening and Responding service.
I want to invoke it as a independent thread from the servet.

so that the thread's execution will continue even the servlet finishes its execution.

Is it possible?

(Thanks in advance for your kind help.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that (unless you are on App Engine or some other severely restricted platform).

Instead of just spawning a new thread directly from the servlet, consider using an ExecutorService, that you can create and shut down in a ServletContextListener (so that when the container decides to stop your application, it does not leave active background threads around that cannot be cleaned up).

Comment: Thilo: Thanks for pointing me towards the right direction. The example from the below url helped me a lot to find the solution: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0160__Thread/CreateExecutorServicetomanagethreads.htm